# Is there a well-defined way to compute the x-coordinate of the right edge of an svg text element?

Tags: svg, pysvg

Suppose I have the following text element, and it is left-aligned as below.

```
<text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" y="134.799806172" x="450"  >
 Foo Bar</text>
```

Observe that `text-anchor` is `start`, so I am providing the `x` and `y` coordinates of the left edge.

**Is there a well-defined way to compute the right edge of this text element?**

To give some context, this element must be left-aligned because it has to line up with other elements on the left.

However, I want to have a different element that is center-aligned with this element, so I want to compute the right edge and thereby find the center.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getBBox()`, example:

```
var text = document.querySelector("text");
var bbox = text.getBBox();
```

`bbox` will be an object with `width`, `height`, `x` and `y` properties.

Comment: This a reasonable answer given how the question was phrased, so +1, but I cannot use it because it uses a JS function and I am creating SVG's using Python. No fault of yours though.